# C language equivalent to ./folder?

Tags: c, fopen, subdirectory, pelles-c

I am working on a C project in Pelles C and I am looking to fopen csv files within a subdirectory of my project folder. 
Right now I have my absolute pathway to the files like so:

```
fopen("F:my/path/projectfolder/datafolder/data.csv", "r");
```

and this works no problem. But I am looking to make my code adaptable for when I move my project folder (say out of my F:/ usb drive to my C:/ harddrive). I would like to know if there is a way to do this without having to change the absolute file path each time I move my project folder.

Basically I am wondering how to say "currentdirectory/datafolder" like in linux ("./datafolder"). Something like the following lines, which I have tested but do not work:

```
fopen("./datafolder/data.csv","r");
```

or

```
fopen("../datafolder/data.csv","r");
```

Thoughts?

Comment: FYI. `.` and `..` are not Linux specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the correct syntax, except it is based on your current working directory.

- To read the current working directory, you could use: [`getcwd()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getcwd)
- To change the current working directory, you could use: [`chdir()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.
However I am running into an issue with Pelles C and that library (unistd.h). I get the following error. I tried Google-ing it a bit but I can't seem to find what to do here.

`<unistd.h> requires -Go compiler option!`

Comment: @Madi_FTW: I won't be able to help you with that. I've never used Pelles C before. You could post a separate question asking how to use `getcwd()` and `chdir()` with your particular compiler.